# How to get eclipse to ignore test source directory

Tags: java, eclipse, testing

First of all I use Eclipse Juno.

I have a simple java project with 2 source directories:

```
-- Project
  |-- src
    |-- main
    |-- test
```

I set these folders in the `build` path and works fine and all. But there are 2 issues I have with eclipse using this approach:

1) The 'src' directory is showed as a separate folder in my package explorer. Is there a way to hide that?
2) When coding in the main directory I can still reference to test related classes. Now I know it's stupid if you would actually do that but I find it clutters my content assist for instance. Can I somehow force to remove the reference from main to test? Or at least remove it from my content assist list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test classes have a different package name. So you can add them in the `Type Filters` to prevent them from appearing in the autocomplete list / content assist as well as when you use the `Open Type... (Ctrl+Shift+T)` functionality.

So, if your test class packages start with `com.test.blah`, add this prefix to the type filters as follows:

1. Window >> Preferences
2. Java >> Appearance >> Type Filters (or enter *Type Filters* in the search box)
3. Click `Add...`
4. Enter `com.test.blah.*`
5. Apply >> OK

And.. you're done.

Regarding your `src` folder showing up as a separate folder, it is by design. You may switch to the `Project Explorer` view if needed. However, is is dependant on the type of the perspective... i.e. `Java EE` perspective will show it different than the `Java` perspective

Comment: This only works if (which in my case i actually do) the test cases have a different package name. And can't say i like the Project explorer. I have the Java perspective but that is different from the package explorer (like it's not grouping jar files that are in the classpath but listing them all under the root). If those are my only options i can live with just an empty 'src' folder in the root...